# Watir: How I can click button in IE popup windows

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a customized popup IE window where there are buttons included into iframe. I can't click on any button in it. I know how to work with iframes, but I can't switch to this window. Window has title and URL.

I wrote this method:

```
  def confirm_ok
    self.in_iframe(:id => 'frmMain') do |frame|
      self.button_element(:id => 'btnOK', :frame => frame).click
    end
  end
```

But I get this error:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownFrameException: unable to locate iframe using {:id=>"frmMain", :tag_name=>"iframe"}
```

I use Watir, PageObject. And run scenarios under IE.

Watir's method doesn't work:

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end
```

I get error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `window' for #<PA_Main:0x33f6780>
```

Comment: The Watir::Browser class has a window method, is PA_Main a subclass of Browser, or is the browser variable pointing to the wrong thing?

Comment: PA_Main is a class of main page, and when I try for example to delete some item I get IE popup window. And I need to click OK button in it. I also have class for popup window, because this a usual page which set to not resizable size. Watir window doesn't work or I use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell you have two separate issues.

Firstly, I have no idea how you set your browser variable to a page object instance. The [Page Object Module](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/blob/master/lib/page-object.rb) definitely sets `browser` as a readable attribute.

So if the code is within a class that has `import PageObject`, you should be able to do `browser.window(...)` just fine.

If you are using the code outside of such a class, you need to make sure that you are in a scope that has access to the Watir::Browser instance. If you have a page object defined, you can use it like: `my_page_object.browser.window(...)`

Secondly - based on what you are describing, the iframe usage has to be combined with the window usage:

`browser.window(title: "annoying popup") do
  browser.iframe(id: 'frmMain').button(id: "close").click
end`